# Linq Group by having

Tags: .net, linq

i'm new to linq, what i want is to do group by  with having like in tqsl.
my class:

```
class test{
public int field1;
public int field2;
public int field3;
}
```

now i have:

```
IEnumerable<test> list;
```

i want something like:

```
IEnumerable<test> q=
from p
in list
group p by p.field1
having p.field2==p.field2.Max()
select p;
```

Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the where-keyword, LINQ will sort it out for you.

EDIT: 
[Some nice examples on the use of LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Comment: i dont need sort, i need group by

Comment: I don't literally mean "sorting", it's just an expression in english. I mean LINQ will make the distinction internally, without you having to worry about it.

Comment: how can i write MAX condition in WHERE?

Comment: You'd have to use a where statement like this: group p by p.field1 into g where g.Key == g.Max(obj=> obj.field2)